# After data inserting some data get removed automatically from database table from my WordPress site

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am using WordPress for my website. After some days randomly some data get removed automatically from database table. what could be the possible reason for this issue?

I have already checked Cron Jobs, Plugin and Theme Issue. But Can't find any reason.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCZCL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check already Cron Jobs, Plugin and Theme.
make sure checking few things.

1. Is your nulled? if nulled then install some theme from WordPress.
2. Avoid test/free hosting
3. Export your posts, product and categories etc. along with your
   logo/images.
4. Create new database and install WordPress again and import
   post/products.

if problem not solve -->contact your hosting provider